# What are the sizes of the components in the UIDatePicker in Date time mode?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make a pickerview with simular values as the UIDatePicker and to make it look good I need to set the component widths to the same as the 4 columns in the date picker so I need the widths of the columns in point value please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know there is no *supported* way to do that, the suggestion below is an *invitation* to experiment if you are not afraid of hacks.

The docs state:

> UIDatePicker does not inherit from UIPickerView, but it manages a custom picker-view object as a subview.

It is a hint that one of `UIDatePicker`'s subviews is a `UIPickerView` (the fact check is left as an exercise to the original poster). You can iterate through `UIDatePicker`'s subviews and find the `UIPickerView`. Now, `UIPickerView` responds to `rowSizeForComponent:`, which should return the correct size for each column. If you see absurd values, make sure you do that after the `UIPickerView` completes `layoutSubviews` (send it `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`).

Even if the above works out right, you should be aware it's a hack which may break with any iOS update. Take extreme caution.

Comment: I **STRONGLY** discourage anyone from doing this.  Those views are private for a reason, and depending on specific private view hierarchies in your app is one of the best ways you can ensure that your app will break in a future update.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Yes, the internal structure of any UIKit view is just that, _an internal implementation detail subject to change_. However, there are "graceful" (if the word is applicable in this context) hacks, which don't break functionality and fail as soon as they detect they no longer work. Not that I encourage such things, but they can be done as an experiment to understand how things work and what's going on.

Comment: if you're going to go to all that trouble to degrade gracefully, why not just write the correct code in the first place and compute an appropriate size for the wheels yourself?

Comment: @DaveDeLong Because you cannot reproduce the calculations? Anyway, you're absolutely right. Do you think I should delete my answer to avoid encouraging dangerous practices? Or is a warning enough? This is an honest question. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: no need to delete the answer; I just want to stress that poking around in the innards of private view hierarchies is a really really really bad idea. If you've found a legitimate need to do it because the API doesn't let you do something you think you need, you should request that the API be enhanced: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: If I were to do this i would only do it once to print out the numbers then hard code the numbers into my app

Comment: so instead of finding the view with code i just put in a breakpoint in view did appear and then went through the datepicker in the debugger and found the pickerview then the selection bars and printed the description of each and found the sizes are 145, 48, 48, 48. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The widths are dynamically generated based on things like the locale, the calendar, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get the widths tho?